# Free AVI to MPG converter

Tags: video, conversion, avi, mpg

Does anyone know of a good and free AVI->MPG converter with *no restrictions*?

I downloaded a trial version of ImToo AVI MPEG converter, but it only allows you to convert 5 minutes of video.

Comment: Yeah this is a good question - when I try to google programs for video conversion I find hundreds of programs that list themselves on freeware sites but infact are only free for 30 days or whatever

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/freemake-video-converter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a superuser command-line approach with more control, [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) will do this. You can find all of the more advanced tweaking options [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html). A basic conversion would look like so:

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -target vcd /tmp/vcd.mpg
```

For a GUI [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html) is great:

[image]

Both are free and open source, don't think it gets any less restrictive than that.

Answer (score 5):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) or [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Quick Media Converter](http://www.cocoonsoftware.com/). No restrictions at all, and very little it can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

The open source [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) can convert pretty much anything and has a nice Windows GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`mencoder` (part of [`mpalyer`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html)) uses FFMpeg and other supporting library, and supplies a uniform command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

use media-convert.com it works very well, but the downside is its online.
VLC can also do it, but I'm not exactly sure how. (its got to be a very recent version of VLC)